# Python Image Url Extraction

Tags: python

I am uploading an image to a wordpress site. How can I get the url of the image? The library is at this link. I am sharing the codes.  https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/methods.html#wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.demo.SayHello

```
            filename = 'C:\\Users\\Image_1.jpg'
```

## prepare metadata

```
        data = {
    'name': 'Image_1.jpg',
    'type': 'image/jpeg',  # mimetype
```

}

## read the binary file and let the XMLRPC library encode it into base64

with open(filename, 'rb') as img:
data['bits'] = xmlrpc_client.Binary(img.read())

```
    response = client.call(media.UploadFile(data))

    attachment_id = response['id']
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs you linked: https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/methods.html#wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.media.UploadFile

it says that the `media.UploadFile` method:

> Returns: dict with keys id, file (filename), url (public URL), and type (MIME-type).

so you should be able to get the url of uploaded image in `response["url"]`